# AUTO_INCREMENT for two tables

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have two tables in my database for users:

`users`

```
id|username|password|registration_date|
1 |bruce   |******  |2017-03-04       |
2 |jason   |*****   |2017-03-06       |
3 |brad    |******* |2017-03-12       |
```

`google_users`

```
id|username|password|registration_date|
1 |jimmy   |*****   |2017-03-05       |
2 |wade    |******* |2017-03-08       |
```

I want to apply the same `AUTO_INCREMENT` index for both tables when a new user signs up with google.

Something like this:

`users`

```
id|username|password|registration_date|
1 |bruce   |******  |2017-03-04       |
3 |jason   |*****   |2017-03-06       |
5 |brad    |******* |2017-03-12       |
```

`google_users`

```
id|username|password|registration_date|
2 |jimmy   |*****   |2017-03-05       |
4 |wade    |******* |2017-03-08       |
```

How can I do this?

Comment: they are the same tables please update the question

Comment: id is diffrent.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to vote against this table design and recommend that that you just maintain a single users table:

```
users (id, username, password, registration_date)
```

To keep track of the method by which they signed up, you may create a second table:

```
accounts (id, user_id, type_id)
```

The `type_id` can point to yet a third table, indicating whether Google or something else were the source of the signup.  Note also that the `accounts` table can have a user with more than one signup relationship, if you would need that.

The basic idea is that maintaining an auto increment column across two tables will either be impossible, or at the very least ugly.  This is not a feature which is usually supported/needed in SQL.  So if you find yourself having this need, you should first look closely at your database design.

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted to say but he needs his design

Comment: @BasilBattikhi That design is flawed.  How can an app even find a user?  It would have to search multiple tables.  This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: are you sure this is impossible??

Comment: Few things are impossible, but maintaining auto increment across two tables does not ship with MySQL out of the box AFAIK.  So you would have to build it yourself.  A lot of work for a DB design which could be made much simpler.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen me neither i'm completely agreed with your answer,
if your design applied then he can get all users throw left join on tables, this lets you actually to signup with multiple social media accounts not only google

Answer (score 1):

Not suggested, but if you really want it to happen this way:

You can try to implement this setting in MySQL:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| auto_increment_increment | 2     |
```

and then for your tables, you can do:

```
ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
ALTER TABLE google_users AUTO_INCREMENT = 2;
```

So, now, your auto-increment will be incremented by 2 and it gives you the expected result.

But as I said, this will impact your whole DB. All your increments will be done by 2 instead of 1.

Comment: How does this guarantee the expected ordering?  The two auto increment IDs know nothing of each other.

Comment: You are right. It won't. I just looked at the expected result but didn't understand what he actually wanted to do.

Comment: Well you might be onto something, if we knew that inserts to both tables always happened in unicen then we could stagger the IDs.